# Tell fswatch to clear screen before running command?

Tags: command-line, terminal

I have the following ruby script, `foo`, that I'm watching with `fswatch`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts "hello world!"
```

on the command line the output looks like:

```
➜  ~/w/s/g/m/todo master ✗ fswatch bin/* | xargs -I {} bundle exec {}
hello world!
^C
```

Which seems all good, and as expected, I'm wondering, how would I tell `fswatch` to clear the screen before running the the `bundle exec`? Or write some sort of bash script to achieve the same goal or watching my files and running my commands but clearing the screen before-hand?

Answer (score 2):

Recently had to figure this out myself. Try:

`fswatch bin/* | xargs -I {} sh -c 'clear && bundle exec {}'`

**Edit**: Completely clearing the scrollback buffer will depend upon the actual terminal emulator program used. As an example, on `macOS` you could do one of the following:

- Terminal: The menu command is `Edit > Clear to Start` or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>, so you could [automate that in applescript](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31872/how-do-i-reset-the-scrollback-in-the-terminal-via-a-shell-command) and call in place of `clear`
- iTerm: supports handy [proprietary escape codes](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-escape-codes.html) - simply replace `clear` with 
  `printf "\033]1337;ClearScrollback\007"`

Comment: that almost clears it. it keeps the past stuff in the terminal, but aligns the new content at the top of the page and puts a big empty block above it. How do you clear it completely so u dont get lost if you accidentally scroll too far up to the top?

Comment: @faceyspacey.com please see edit